# Change button text based on Username in mvc

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have a scenario where I want to change the `button text` depending upon the which user is logged in. Also,  I get the logged user info like below

```
@ViewBag.CurrentGroupName
```

Also here is my button html

```
<input type="button" class="button approve" value="Accept" onclick="return SaveFiberData('Approve');" />
```

Now what I want is

if `CurrentGroupName == FL and CurrentGroupName == FE` then text should be `Accept` else it should be `Approve`.

How should I do it in `MVC`

Comment: What is the issue in using a conditional statement ?

Comment: @Shyju: there is no issue in using it. I need to check for the conditional statement now as u told. I am learning mvc now :)

Comment: You want to change the text based on the UserName or the value of `ViewBag.CurrentGroupName` ?

Comment: @Shyju: yes,  i want that exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can conditionally render the value attribute value of the button

```
<input type="button" class="btn"
       value="@((ViewBag.CurrentGroupName=="FL"||ViewBag.CurrentGroupName=="FE")?
                                                 Html.Raw("Accept"):Html.Raw("Approve"))"
     onclick="return SaveFiberData('@((ViewBag.CurrentGroupName=="FL"||
       ViewBag.CurrentGroupName=="FE")? Html.Raw("Accept"):Html.Raw("Approve"))');" />
```

While this works, I would recommend moving the if condition check to a helper method and use that. So if you ever have to add a third state to the condition, you make the change in a single place.

You can create a custom html helper and use that to render your button.

Create a view called `MyHelper.cshtml` inside the `App_Code` folder (create one in the web app root if that does not exist). Add the below helper method code to that

```
@helper  MyButton(string item)
{
     var b = "Approve";
     if (item != null && (item == "FL" || item == "FE"))
     {
         b = "Accept";
     }
     <input type="button" class="btn" value="@b" onclick="return SaveFiberData('@b')" />
}
```

Now in your view, you can call this helper

```
@MyHelper.MyButton(ViewBag.CurrentGroupName)
```

Comment: yes, you are right, will move that..let me check with your code. One doubt here -> why did you added the conditional part for `onclick`, as it is already working for me. any special reason ?

Comment: I just added it thinking that you might need the "Accept" or "Reject" in the js method as well. Just check the view source of the rendered page and you will understand what happened

Comment: ok, but i always get `Approve` only not accept.. here is my code `<input type="button" class="button" value="@((ViewBag.CurrentGroupName == "FE" || ViewBag.CurrentGroupName == "FL") ? Html.Raw("Accept") : Html.Raw("Approve"))" onclick="return SaveFiberData('Approve');" />`

Comment: You have `Approve` in both the cases, compare it carefully with the answer. (one should be approve and one should be reject) (`? Html.Raw("Accept") : Html.Raw("Reject")`)

Comment: i know, i want `Approve` and `Accept`. I never said `Reject`. my issue is I always get `Approve` text not the `Accept` inspite if my user is `FE` . for helper class details, I upvoted ur answer :)

Comment: Print the `ViewBag.CurrentGroupName` value and see whether you are getting as expected (`<h1>@ViewBag.CurrentGroupName</h1>`)

Comment: how should I print it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161982/discussion-between-shyju-and-vvvv).

Comment: Sorry, in place of `FE` and `FL` i wanted to call `Fiber Engineer` and `Fiber lead` respectively. now it is working with your code. Thanks a lot :)